# scala implicit parameter type inference

Tags: scala

Running the following script under scala 2.10.4. I was expecting the result of a.classOp should be MyPage. Why it is nothing?

```
scala> trait PageModel {
 | def classOp[T](implicit manifest: Manifest[T]) {
 |  println("Class: " + manifest.runtimeClass.getName)
 | }
 | }
defined trait PageModel

scala> class MyPage extends PageModel
defined class MyPage

scala> val a = new MyPage
a: MyPage = MyPage@1f2f992

scala> a.classOp
Class: scala.runtime.Nothing$
```

**Edited:**

I think I get the answer. Thanks!
However, it is very interesting that the same code running on 2.9.3 gives me a java.lang.Object. Should it behave the same? I see NoManifest in 2.9.3 as well.

```
scala> trait PageModel{
 |  def classOp[T](implicit m: Manifest[T]) {
 |    println("Class: " + manifest[T].erasure.getName)
 |  }
 | }
defined trait PageModel

scala> class MyPage extends PageModel
defined class MyPage

scala> val a = new MyPage
a: MyPage = MyPage@f7bf869

scala> a.classOp
Class: java.lang.Object
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you define this method `def classOp[T](...)` what is `T` constrained to? It can essentially be anything, so you're requesting an implicit manifest for a type `T` that can be anything: `implicit manifest: Manifest[T]`.

If you look in `scala.Predef` you can see the following declaration:

```
val NoManifest = scala.reflect.NoManifest
```

Where `NoManifest` is:

```
object NoManifest extends OptManifest[Nothing]
```

And where `OptManifest` is:

```
/** A `OptManifest[T]` is an optional [[scala.reflect.Manifest]].
 *  It is either a `Manifest` or the value `NoManifest`.
```

So what does all this translate to?

Since `Nothing` is the subtype of all types and there is always a `Manifest[Nothing]` in scope (`Predef` is always in scope) it will mean that this implicit will be injected when nothing else is found.

---

With this said, I agree with Ryan and you probably meant to do:

```
trait PageModel[T] {
 def classOp(implicit manifest: Manifest[T]) {
   println("Class: " + manifest.runtimeClass.getName)
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant to parameterize `PageModel` on its subclass, since right now `a.classOp` doesn't have anything to fill in `T` with so the compiler goes for the bottom type, `Nothing`.

For instance:

```
scala> a.classOp[String]
java.lang.String
```

I'm assuming you were hoping to get the class name of `MyPage`.  In that case, you need to parameterize `PageModel` on its subtype:

```
trait PageModel[T] {
  def classOp(implicit manifest: Manifest[T]) =
    println("Class: " + manifest.runtimeClass.getName)
}


class MyPage extends PageModel[MyPage]

val a = new MyPage

a.classOp // prints "Class: $line11.$read$$iw$$iw$MyPageModel"
```

Obviously outside the REPL `classOp` would print a more readable FQCN.